# Hindi matra misplaced in subtitles burned with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, handbrake

When trying to burn in subtitles, I get 
[incorrectly shaped subs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfwoo.jpg), when the text should have actually read  *कहानियों के बारे में*
The command was 
`ffmpeg -i ~/in.mp4 -y -vf subtitles=~/hindi.srt:force_style='Fontname=Noto Sans Devanagari' -acodec copy ~/out.mp4`

I can confirm that this works correctly with Handbrake GUI (v1.2.2), HandBrakeCli and even adding the subs as a stream with the `mov_text` codec when viewed on VLC Media player.

I have some more information in this [Github issue](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/issues/1654) I posted.
I would really appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you get any solution?